# Is it possible to modify @title?

Tags: titles, report

In the following example, I would like to make the "look" of the title of the document same as that of a chapter heading.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Footer Testing}
\date{January 3, 2012}\maketitle

\chapter*{Preface}
\begin{flushleft}
\lipsum[1]\par
 \chapter*{What is footer?}
 \lipsum[2]
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

One thing led to another, and I was looking at [report.cls](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) after a while.

In other words I like the `\huge\bfseries` chapter headings, and would like to use the same `huge\bfseries` for the title of the document. (I looked at the definition of `\makechapterhead` in `report.cls` to come to this conclusion.  Please correct me if I am wrong.)  However, I could not find the definition of `@title` in `report.cls`. (It seems `@title` is more fundamental.)

Is it possible to change the "look" of the `@title` to match the look of a chapter title, one way or another?

Comment: In answer to your question, "Yes". But *how* do you want the title to be the same as `\chapter*`? Do you want the same spacing as well, but with the `\chapter*` formatting/font? Also, what happens to `\date`? What should happen to `\author`?  Do you print them in paragraph form or leave them as-is? Do you still want to use the same interface (via `\maketitle`)?

Comment: I would like to have them as is.  If I can learn how to change the `\title` then I think I could use that knowledge to change `\author ` and `\date` if necessary.  At this point, I am only interested in the title.  Yes.  I would like to have the same look, if that means including formatting, font(definitely), and spacing.  I am not particular about `\maketitle` as long as I can get the same look by any means.  For example, if you can use \titling package to get it done then I do not mind.  However, reading the manual of the titling package did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the result by doing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \title{\huge\bfseries Footer Testing} % already scoped in  report.cls
    \date{January 3, 2012}\maketitle


    \chapter*{Preface}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \lipsum[1]\par
        \chapter*{What is footer?}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

For better customization the `titlepage` environment might be interesting. I took a look at `report.cls`. `@title` is only saving the title. Here a quote from report.cls of the relevant part.

```
\def\ps@myheadings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \let\chaptermark\@gobble
    \let\sectionmark\@gobble
    }
  \if@titlepage
  \newcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
  \end{center}\par
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
\else
\newcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent
            \hb@xt@1.8em{%
                \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}##1}%
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
```

Comment: `\title{\huge\bfseries Footer Testing} % already scoped in  report.cls`  That was easy!  But, why did not I pick it up while reading the report.cls?  Thanks you very much.  I will have to spend some time to understand your second solution.

Comment: I just realized that you did not submit a second solution.  This is part of the report.cls.  It is like DeJaVu. :)  Anyway, I do not fully understand how report.cls works.  (I need time and I do not have enough of it now.)

Comment: I just was thinking the quote from report.cls would help to understand the solution :D. I'll edit it so that this is clear.

Answer (score 4):

First, a comment. If you wish to see the definition of some command, you can prefix it with `\show` and inspect your `.log` file. Note that this will show the definition of the command as it is defined *at that particular moment*. For completeness, `\@title` is defined within [`latex.ltx`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) as

```
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}}
\def\@title{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\title given}\@ehc}
```

which either sets `\@title` to be the same as `\title` (if you have a use `\title`), or it sets it as an error macro (if you don't use `\title`).

@someonr's answer provides the easiest way to format the title font in to your specifications. Note that `\chapter` and `\chapter*` formats the heading in `\Huge\bfseries`.

In order to modify the vertical alignment of `\maketitle` to match that of `\chapter*` (I assume you wish to keep the horizontal alignment/centering), a little more works needs to be done. You could just typeset it as a centered, unnumbered chapter using

```
\makeatletter
\title{Footer Testing}
\chapter*{\makebox[\linewidth]{\@title}}
\makeatother
```

but this will not typeset all the other title-related content with it. As such, perhaps a redefinition of `\maketitle` would work. Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let\footnote\thanks
  \chapter*{\makebox[\linewidth]{\@title}}
  \begin{center}
    \vskip\dimexpr 3em-40\p@\relax%
    {\large \lineskip .75em%
     \begin{tabular}[t]{c} \@author \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%
  \end{center}\par
  \@thanks
  \vfill\null\setcounter{footnote}{0}
  %\thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-1}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\title{Footer Testing}
\date{January 3, 2012}
\author{Random Randofsky\thanks{Yo mama}}
\maketitle

\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter*{What is footer?}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

If you wish to remove the footer (page number) on the first/title page, uncomment the last line of `\maketitle` which sets the page style to `empty`, and "resets" the `page` counter.

Comment: A great exposition in the usual Werner style.  It is good to know about the `\show` command.  I (occasionally) wondered if there is a command in LaTeX similar to that of Maple `?`.

Comment: Best.  Footnote.  Ever.